# OpenCV VideoWriter does not open file

Tags: c++, opencv

The following code fails to open a VideoWriter object:

```
#include <iostream>

#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main() {
    VideoWriter oVideo;
    oVideo.open ("381.avi", -1, 30, Size(640,480), true);
    if (!oVideo.isOpened()) {
        cout  << "Could not open the output video for write" << endl;
        return -1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I'm running OpenCV 2.4.9 pre-built with Code::Blocks on Ubuntu 12.04. I've written a number of images using `imwrite()` on the same location without issue, so I doubt it has to do with permissions. Also I tried `CV_FOURCC('X','V','I','D')` which did not work.

What am I missing here?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Instead of -1, try passing argument `CV_FOURCC('M', 'J', 'P', 'J')`. Or `('M','P','E','G')`. XVID may not be a codec present in your system.

Comment: Does it give you any errors or does it just say "Could not open the output video for write"? I copied your code directly and only changed the file name to a video that I had, and It worked just fine. What is the end goal your trying to achieve

Comment: -1 is supposed to give me a pop-up menu right? This does not happen. Also, I've now tried MJPJ, MPEG, PIM1 but I get the same result.

Comment: It compiles and runs without any errors, I just get the output "could not open the output video for write". Ultimately I want to write a number of frames to the video, but since my code already failed at the first step of creating a VideoWriter object, I made it into a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: @BdB... value of `-1` or `CV_FOURCC_PROMPT` for fourcc is supported on windows only. On other platforms, you have to specify a fourcc value.

Comment: try `CV_FOURCC_DEFAULT` or `CV_FOURCC('I', 'Y', 'U', 'V')` which are default for linux.

Comment: oVideo.open("381.avi", CV_FOURCC_DEFAULT, 30, Size(480,640), true); and oVideo.open("381.avi", CV_FOURCC('I','Y','U','V'), 30, Size(480,640), true); both give the same result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reinstalled OpenCV using this amazing script: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/OpenCV

Solved.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure specific codec is installed in your machine.

Comment: It seems the default codecs (xvid, mjpj, mpeg, iyuv) and no compression (0 or CV_FOURCC_DEFAULT) are not functioning so I doubt it's a codec problem. To be sure, how do I find out which codec are installed on my system?

Answer (score 0):

Just for reference for anyone coming across a similar problem in OpenCV 4.6 in Windows it is worth noting that the pre-built opencv_world460.lib does not appear to support video codecs outside of API and I found I needed to rebuild and link all the individual libraries in the opencv\build\lib\Release folders after ffmpeg had been installed.